# Can't export Content query web part

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell

I configured a CQWP,  but export option not found

Can export CQWP using power shell

Appreciate your help thanks

Comment: Have you checked as per the #Supermode?

Comment: What is super mode?

Comment: Hey It's an User who given answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

Edit webpart. Under Export Mode under Advanced Section, ensure Export all data selected. Refer to the image attached.[image]

**Solution 2**

Use exportwp page

e.q:

https://intranet.contoso.com/_vti_bin/exportwp.aspx?pageurl=https://intranet.contoso.com/Pages/default.aspx&guidstring=0c3adfe9-8f5d-4432-918a-42410e4e324d

Using example above, Replace your site address, page file url
and Guidstring which is your webpart id.
https://chuvash.eu/2014/09/19/export-any-web-part-from-a-sharepoint-page/

Comment: Thanks for your answer,  I will check this solution and inform you the result, in the same time I need powershell script if it possible,  please help me!   I appreciate your help

Comment: Hi what's guid string!

Answer (score 1):

If your goal to export the web part, instead of Power Shell , there is another method that you can use to export your web part via `/_vti_bin/exportwp.aspx` as the following :

- Open your page that contains your web part.
- Click F12 > select your content Query web part > pick up the web part ID.

[image]

- Replace the following with your values `http://yoursite/_vti_bin/exportwp.aspx?pageurl=your page&guidstring=webpartid`

**Eg:**

```
http://qassassite/_vti_bin/exportwp.aspx?pageurl=http://qassassite/Pages/default.aspx&guidstring=35f6485d-ab7e-46d4-99ad-833acf91b299
```

- Put it in your browser , this will export the web part to `yourwebpart.webpart`

Answer (score 0):

To export CQWP through browser 
[image]

Comment: This option is not available

Comment: Add screen shot of your Web part in edit mode